# colouring rows based on id of model

Tags: html, css, .net, asp.net-mvc

i want unique color to the table rows to identify all records of that InternalTaskID (which can be taken from Model) currently I'm doing this...

```
    @{
       var rowColor = "#dfd6fa";
     }

     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
          if(item.InternalTaskID.Equals(Unique_TaskIDs.First()))
          {
            rowColor = "#dfd6fa";
          }
          else
          {
            rowColor = "#ffffff";
          }
          <tr style="background-color:@rowColor;">
          ...
          ...
         </tr>
     }
```

but this will work only for rows with the same first id, currently i need to know

1. How to get unlimited supply of unique colours and use them without repetition
2. assigning these colors to the Unique_ids
3. combine Unique_ids and unique_colors to get the required View

how do i do it?

Comment: If you were to be totally random in the full spectrum of 16Million colors (#000000 - #FFFFFF) there would be the risk of shades being too light or dark as well as adjacent colors being too close. When you say unlimited supply of unique colors, what is the realistic top range of unique colors that you would need?

Comment: it can be 100 , i thought we could do it by setting up a variable to dim color initially and incrementing it by a number which would get next dim color and so on..,